# Fatal erro oci_connect

Tags: php, sql, oracle

Tenho um banco `oracle` que está em uma maquina virtual, e estou fazendo um trabalho da universidade eu gostaria de conectar esse sistema web nesse banco.

Eis que surgem as duvidas, preciso instalar alguma aplicação na maquina física?

Segue meu codigo `php` da seguinte forma:

```
$ora_senha="1234";

$oracle_bd="(DESCRIPTION=
                (ADDRESS_LIST=
                    (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)
                        (HOST=10.0.0.10)(PORT=1521)
                )
            )
            (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=teste))
            )";

if ($ora_conexao = oci_connect( $ora_usuario, $ora_senha, oracle_bd) ){
    echo "conexão com o banco oracle foi feita com sucesso";
} 
else
  echo "erro na conexão com o banco";
?>
```

Porém o oci_connect(); não conecta de forma alguma sempre da o seguinte erro:

> "Fatal error: Call to undefined function oci_connect() in"

Já fiz tudo, descomentei as extensões no `php.ini` ja baixei o arquivo instantclient mas sempre recebo este erro!